# Bucle en un rango de hora en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito ayuda, quisiera saber como hacer un bucle en un rango de fechas.  
Por ejemplo: 
 
Tengo el horario inicio de **2020-03-11 00:00:00** a 
Hora fin de **2020-03-11 02:30:00**. 
Y a parte, de que ese bucle, sea con una separación de 30 min
Entonces quiero que mi resultado sea algo asi.

```
2020-03-11 00:00:00
2020-03-11 00:30:00
2020-03-11 01:00:00
2020-03-11 01:30:00
```

Así hasta llega a la hora fin.

Si tienen una solución, se le agradecería mucho.
Estoy usando PHP y MySql para hacer esto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [DateTime::modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php) para hacer alteraciones en variables tipo DateTime, como sumar minutos, horas, días, meses... a una fecha especificada.

Esto imprime lo que estas buscando

```
<?php
$inicio = '2020-03-11 00:00:00';
$final = '2020-03-11 02:30:00';
$incr = 30; // Minutos

$date_obj = new DateTime($inicio);
$date_incr = $inicio;
while($date_incr < $final) {
    $date_incr = $date_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $date_incr . PHP_EOL;
    $date_obj->modify('+'.$incr.' minutes');
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, si me sirvió muchísimo! CRACK